# How sublime replace some word

Tags: replace, words

How can I replace some words by sublime text 3, for example:

```
function test()
    print("test t")
    print("test t")
    print("test t")
end
```

I just want to replace the ‘t’ to 'a' which in 'test t', like print("test a").
Thanks.

Comment: In addition, i just want replace the word that in function test, not whole file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, select this - ***t"***, press `ctrl + h`, type this - ***a"*** as a replacement & hit enter!

Another way - select ***t"*** and press `ctrl + d` for no. of times as per your expected count of matching words; no. of cursors will select that much words & then type your replacement. That's it!